# Does data referenced from the Platform Cache consume heap space?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, platform-cache

Reading [Platform Cache Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_limits.htm), it appears that an individual request can obtain up to 1 MB of data from the Platform Cache:

> Maximum local cache size for a partition, per-request 1,000 KB
>   ...
>   Local cache
>   is the application server’s in-memory container that the client
>   interacts with during a request.

Does that 1 MB consume from 6 MB heap limit?

(My guess is yes, and yes I can write a test to confirm this; looking for a quick answer though if anyone else has explored this.)

Comment: @KeithC, I see you are almost at 100000 reputation! Upvoting question to get you closer :D

Comment: Please refer this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_cache_partition_setup.htm

Comment: Thanks @PhilW; hope the question is of some interest too.

Comment: Hi @RohitMourya, I'm not seeing anything about heap in that link...

Comment: @KeithC My understanding is that it depends on the way of creation. If Platform cache is created using Session then it will use heap size otherwise it will use org cache. However I could be wrong. Let's see if anyone posts any answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the data is loaded to memory the heap size is consumed.

I uploaded a book (around 1.5mb) to my org as an attachment, and then split it into several 100kb or less parts to the org's cache. Turns out the heap is consumed to store the file in memory, but when you put it into the cache, it doesn't consume more of it.

```
// Fill in the 2mb cache with a book as attachment
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
Attachment a = [SELECT Id, Body, BodyLength FROM Attachment LIMIT 1];

Integer parts = 100;
Integer partsize = a.BodyLength / parts;

String bodystr = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(a.Body);
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
for (Integer i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
    Integer start = i * partsize;
    Integer endx = (i + 1) * partsize;
    Cache.Org.put('local.LimitTest.bigString' + i, bodystr.substring(start, endx));
}
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
```

> 18:53:45:002 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|1064
>
> 18:53:45:202 USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|8256123 (+8255059)
>
> 18:53:45:574 USER_DEBUG [15]|DEBUG|8256667 (+544)

Notice how on the third call (after the loop) the difference of used heap size is minimal. That probably means that Salesforce might use pointers internally to reference the cache, or it doesn't count against the heap because you are just inserting data, not reading it. Anyway...

To retrieve it (in a separate transaction, of course):

```
// Retrieve it in chunks
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
List<Object> pieces = new List<Object>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
    Object part = Cache.Org.get('local.LimitTest.bigString' + i);
    pieces.add(part);
}
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
```

> 19:06:19:002 USER_DEBUG [19]|DEBUG|1067
>
> 18:50:54:426 USER_DEBUG [22]|DEBUG|4707383

When the file parts are loaded to memory the heap is also used. I believe that answers the question.

---

#### Why did you split the file?

If you try to set more than 100kb per `.put` call you'll get an `ItemSizeLimitExceededException`:

> cache.ItemSizeLimitExceededException: Value exceeded maximum size limit (100KB): 107.87 KB, 107.9% of limit.

Comment: Thanks Renato, that is exactly what I was looking for. We are struggling with some CPU/heap limit tradeoffs. The `ItemSizeLimitExceededException` looks nasty though; will need to experiment to get the items at the right size for this to work.